# Error while using AlamofireObjectMapper in Swift 2

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, alamofire

I have integrated `AlamofireObjectMapper` through Cocoapods to handle JSON . 
I am getting a number of errors in one of the files of  `AlamofireObjectMapper`:

[image: Errors]

Please post the required steps to resolve the issues. I am new to programming, help me out.

My project structure:

[image: project structure]

**My pod file**

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MT' do
    pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 3.0'
end
```

Comment: Are you sure you have opened [YourProjectName].xcworkspace ? Not the .xcproj and/or the Pods.xcworkspace

Comment: @H4Hugo sure I have opened projectName.xcworkspace

Comment: okay, can you update your post and let us see your Podfile, and maybe your project structure ? It's really hard to help you with few elements

Comment: @H4Hugo I have included the files.

Comment: To me it seems like your project structure is a mess. I cannot tell for sure because I can't see everything. I suggest you try to create a new clean project and properly add pods, run a pod install etc in the top folder of your project. I'm sorry I can't write this as an answer because I cannot be sure it comes from that.